# QLabel taking time to update when QPushButton pressed

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

My goal is to make it so that a QLabel changes its text once we press a QPushButton.

```
class MainWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)        

        self.mylbl = QLabel("Initial Text")

        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setText("Press me!")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.greet)


        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 2)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 4)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mylbl, 1, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button, 2, 0)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    
    def greet(self):
        self.mylbl.setText("Button pressed")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    wgt = MainWidget()
    wgt.resize(800, 400)

    wgt.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

While the code does work, the result could either be immediate or take up to 4 seconds to actually do this change, which leads me to believe I'm missing something.

Comment: what is your OS

Comment: My OS is macOS Mojave

Comment: that's a Qt bug that only happens on macOS

Comment: I was able to kind of cheese my way around this by calling `self.repaint()` inside the `greet()` function. Turns out it's something to do with how QT5 processes events. However, I've also read that `self.repaint()` is not very good and I should use `self.update()` instead, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know where you read that repaint is bad, if it was bad then Qt wouldn't provide it, other than calling repaint repeatedly can cause unnecessary consumption of resources. I recommend you read https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59290-What-s-the-difference-between-calling-QWidget-update()-and-QWidget-repaint()?p=263421#post263421